# SAS PROC TRANSPOSE - reoccurring ID names with "LET"

Tags: sas, transpose

I have a data set with a column named Attribute, where some of the Attributes can be repetitive, as such:

```
Account Attribute
1234    Online
1458    Online
4587    Offline
```

When I use PROC TRANSPOSE, I get the error:

ERROR: The ID value "ClomnOnline" occurs twice in the same BY group.

So I used the **LET** option, but it combines all the data, so if I have multiple accounts under the same attribute, is gives only 1 observation

This is my code:

```
    PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.Final_Sorted LET
    OUT=WORK.Final_transposed(LABEL="Transposed WORK.FINAL_SORTED")
    NAME=Source
    LABEL=Label ;
    BY Account_Branch_Id;
    ID Attribute;
    VAR acc ;
RUN ;
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead when you have multiple values?  What output do you want for your two values of ONLINE?

Comment: I want to have first column named online1 and second named online2. I checked, and it seems that the proc is giving me the latest value for each duplicate value....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to sort the data by attribute within branch **and** compute a sequence value within attribute.  The `sequence` variable can be used in the `ID` statement along with `attribute`.

Example:

```
data have;
input branch $ account attribute $;
datalines;
A    1234  Online
A    1458  Online
A    4587  Offline
A    1972  Online
run;

proc sort data=have equals;
  by branch descending attribute;
run;

data have_v / view = have_v;
  set have;
  by branch descending attribute;
  if first.attribute then sequence = 1; else sequence + 1;
run;

proc transpose data=have_v out=want;
  by branch;
  id attribute sequence;
  var account;
run;
```

[image]